# react-bootstrap breadcrumb with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to use `react-bootstrap` breadcrumb as below.

```
<Breadcrumb>
    <Breadcrumb.Item href="#">Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
    <Breadcrumb.Item><Link to={"/products"}>Products</Link></Breadcrumb.Item>
    <Breadcrumb.Item active>{productName}</Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

As you can expect, `products` Link will render anchor tag inside another anchor tag, which is invalid markup. But `Home` creates a simple anchor tag instead of react's `Link` making the page to reload, making it unusable.

What's the solution for this? Unfortunately, there's no mention of this in `react-bootstrap` doc. ([link](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/breadcrumb/))

Comment: why don't you wrap `<Breadcrumb.Item>` into a Link?

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up dropping react-boostrap and doing it 'by hand':

```
const Breadcrumbs = ({ breadcrumbs }) => (
  <ol className="breadcrumb">
    {breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, index) => (
      <li key={breadcrumb.key}>
        <NavLink to={breadcrumb.props.match.url}>
          {breadcrumb}
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ol>
);
```

Answer (score 23):

I would probably use react-router-bootstrap, but if you don't want to include it as a dependency, you can apply the link by hand using the now available [linkAs and linkProps Breadcrumb params](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/breadcrumb/#breadcrumb-item-props). For instance:

```
<Breadcrumb.Item linkAs={Link} linkProps={{ to: "/path" }}>
  My item
</Breadcrumb.Item>
```

This approach is interesting especially if you are using just the "as" attribute with other components like Button or NavLink.

Answer (score 13):

This nicely works and it does not refresh the whole page, only what's needed to change

```js
import { Breadcrumb } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const SiteMap = ({ hrefIn }) => {
  const items = [
    { href: "/dictionaries", name: "Dictionaries" },
    { href: "/antonyms", name: "Antonyms" },
  ];

  return (
    <Breadcrumb>
      {items.map((item) =>
        item.href === hrefIn ? (
          <Breadcrumb.Item active>{item.name}</Breadcrumb.Item>
        ) : (
          <Breadcrumb.Item linkProps={{ to: item.href }} linkAs={Link}>
            {item.name}
          </Breadcrumb.Item>
        )
      )}
    </Breadcrumb>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6):

It works for me if I wrap `<Breadcrumb.Item>` into the `<LinkContainer>`.
Now outer Breadcrumb "My applications" which points to `/applications` URL redirects my app with react-router to the applications page.

I tested this with react-bootstrap v0.32.4 https://5c507d49471426000887a6a7--react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/breadcrumb/

I got `<LinkContainer>` from react-router-bootstrap package: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap

I saw "the wrapping" here before, though I don't generate breadcrumb in a loop: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/issues/141#issue-122688732

```
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

// and then in the render function

<Breadcrumb>
    <LinkContainer to="/applications" exact>
        <Breadcrumb.Item>My applications</Breadcrumb.Item>
    </LinkContainer>
    <Breadcrumb.Item active>My First Applicaton</Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I have passed `onClick` to `Breadcrumb.Item` to handle navigation with the help of

> `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";`

Here is the sample:

```
const RenderBreadcrumb = ({ breadcrumbInfo, history }) => {
    const handleRedirect = (url) => {
        history.push(url);
    }

    return (
        <Breadcrumb>
            { map(breadcrumbInfo, (item) => {
                if(item.isActive) {
                    return (<Breadcrumb.Item active>{item.text}</Breadcrumb.Item>);
                }
                return (<Breadcrumb.Item onClick={() => { handleRedirect(item.link); }}>{item.text}</Breadcrumb.Item>);
            })}
        </Breadcrumb>
    )
}

export default withRouter(RenderBreadcrumb);
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap.Item internally uses [SafeAnchor](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/SafeAnchor.js) which allows you to not use a link if you don't want to.

Using the `as` prop you can modify what tag is used (`a` by default). For example you can pass:

```
<Bootstrap.Item as="div" />
```

And it will use a div tag for presenting the item.

Comment: I'm using `Typescript` along with React. I'm getting error saying prop `componentClass` doesn't exist.

Comment: You can create an issue for that in this repo: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-bootstrap